# "sys.fm_my_permissions" throwing a syntax error with (

Tags: java, sql-server

When I am trying to execute the following query in `sql server management studio 2012` then it showing an `Incorrect sytax near '('` 
 at line -`fn_my_permissions(QUOTENAME`

```
SELECT 
s.name,
o.name,
o.[type],
p.[permission_name]
FROM sys.objects AS o 
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
CROSS APPLY sys.fn_my_permissions(QUOTENAME(s.name) 
+ N'.' + QUOTENAME(o.name), N'OBJECT') AS p
WHERE o.[type] IN (N'U', N'V',N'FN',N'TF',N'P',N'TR',N'SN') -- tables and views
AND p.subentity_name = N'' order by o.[type] ;
```